# How to define array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get error that "cannot set property xx of undefined to xx"   when try to save a value to a multidimensional array. I had this code working a few weeks ago and now it doesn't.    I am not sure what changed but I believe the error is related t how the array is defined.

```
function iterateSheets() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1ezdV7AHBNyq6aZdqKdvhlOhKMmLPhQoW');//replace id with actual id of folder
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var consol_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1FyuizUjU8W8idMonEp0qFthvTDjfwmnboZivAAozDXU').getActiveSheet();
  consol_sheet.clear()
  var x=0;
  var z=0;
  var final_values = [[]];

while(files.hasNext())
 {
    var file=files.next();
    var ts=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    var allShts=ts.getSheets();


       for(var i=0;i<1;i++)   
       {  
        // if (allShts[i] == "Aug"  || allShts[i] = "Sept")
         //{   
            var consol_values = allShts[i].getRange(8,1,allShts[i].getLastRow(),10).getValues(); 
            var headers = allShts[i].getRange(4,6,1,4).getValues();  
            var position= allShts[i].getRange("B1").getValue();
            var period = allShts[i].getRange("B2").getValue();
            var email = allShts[i].getRange("B3").getValue();    

             for (var z = 0;z<3;z++)//
             {   

               for (var y= 0;y<allShts[i].getLastRow();y++)               
               {          
                 if (consol_values[y][0] != "" && consol_values[y][z+5] !="")     


                 final_values[x] = [];       

                 final_values[x][0]  = consol_values[y][0]  //AI pack 
                 final_values[x][1]  = '1111'
                 final_values[x][2]  = consol_values[y][2]  ; //measure
                 final_values[x][3]  = email ;
                 final_values[x][4]  = position ;     
                 final_values[x][5]  = headers[0][z];//location
                 final_values[x][6]  = 1;
                 final_values[x][7]  = period;
                 final_values[x][8]  = consol_values[y][3]; //price
                 final_values[x][9]  = consol_values[y][z+5]; //fcst

                 if (consol_values[y][z+5] != "")
                 { 
                    final_values[x][10] =(consol_values[y][25]); //fcst value             
                 }                          

                 x = Number(x)+1  //row count for consolidation output

                }
              //}   

         }    
      }

 }


//consol_sheet.getRange(2,1,final_values.length,final_values[0].length).setValues(final_values);

}
```

Any help in what I am doing wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: Which line are you getting this error on?

Comment: final_values[x][0]  = consol_values[y][0]

Comment: I think this `var final_values = [[]];` should be this `var final_values = [];`

Comment: Instead of including the original code add a [mcve] and the textual error message that you was able to reproduce. Include the values of the variables like `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: TheMaster has pointed out that you're already initialising your arrays with `final_values[x] = [];` and after reviewing my answer I agree that they are correct.

The problem is actually your conditional statement:

```
if (consol_values[y][0] != "" && consol_values[y][z+5] !="")
```

Apps script will continue to read a line until it sees a `;`, and so as you haven't contained your `if` block within curly brackets `{}`, when `final_values[x] = [];` is being read it is reading the whole if block as:

```
if (consol_values[y][0] != "" && consol_values[y][z+5] !="") final_values[x] = [];
```

This means that if `consol_values[y][0] != "" && consol_values[y][z+5] !=""` evaluates to `False`, the inner array will never be initialised and you'll get the `cannot set property` error on assigning

```
final_values[x][0]  = consol_values[y][0];
```

Comment: Isn't that already present in his code? `final_values[x] = [];`

Comment: Yes, but JavaScript doesn't handle multi-dimensional arrays to be pushed dynamically so `final_values[x][0]` on its own will throw a `can't set property` error unless the inner array has been initialised first, which is what I'm doing with the conditional.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Isn't the inner array already initialized in his code? His code already contains `final_values[x] = [];`

Comment: @TheMaster You're right! Thank you for pointing that out I overlooked that when testing out the multidimensional arrays. I've worked it out now though so I've edited my answer.